# Error in SVN DepSync with WSO2 APIM Gateway Cluster

Tags: svn, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to deploy wso2 apim in a distributed setup with docker and with svn based depsync in gateway cluster.

Bellow error can be seen in the gateway manager and worker nodes regarding svn depsync.

But SVN server can be accessed with "svn co http://svnrepository/svn/repos/repo repo -user_name admin" from a remote host.

```html
[,977] ERROR - SVNBasedArtifactRepository Error while attempting to create the directory: http://svnrepo/svn/repos/repo/-1234
2017-4-3 17.43.39org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.SVNClientException: org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: E175002: timed out waiting for server
2017-4-3 17.43.39svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/repos/repo'
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.javahl.AbstractJhlClientAdapter.mkdir(AbstractJhlClientAdapter.java:2733)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.subversion.SVNBasedArtifactRepository.checkRemoteDirectory(SVNBasedArtifactRepository.java:248)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.subversion.SVNBasedArtifactRepository.init(SVNBasedArtifactRepository.java:175)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.repository.CarbonRepositoryUtils.newCarbonRepositorySynchronizer(CarbonRepositoryUtils.java:67)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.internal.DeploymentSynchronizerComponent.initDeploymentSynchronizerForSuperTenant(DeploymentSynchronizerComponent.java:98)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.internal.DeploymentSynchronizerComponent.activate(DeploymentSynchronizerComponent.java:67)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:514)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.start(CarbonServerManager.java:219)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.activate(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:94)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1269)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1182)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1072)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5368)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5660)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-4-3 17.43.39Caused by: org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: E175002: timed out waiting for server
2017-4-3 17.43.39svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/repos/repo'
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException.fromException(ClientException.java:68)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl17.SVNClientImpl.getClientException(SVNClientImpl.java:1492)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl17.SVNClientImpl.mkdirRemote(SVNClientImpl.java:2294)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl17.SVNClientImpl.mkdir(SVNClientImpl.java:597)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.javahl.AbstractJhlClientAdapter.mkdir(AbstractJhlClientAdapter.java:2730)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 ... 65 more
2017-4-3 17.43.39Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: timed out waiting for server
2017-4-3 17.43.39svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/repos/repo'
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:106)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:90)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:775)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:375)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:363)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:710)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:627)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:102)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1032)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.checkPath(DAVRepository.java:214)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteRemoteMkDir.addURLParents(SvnRemoteRemoteMkDir.java:156)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteRemoteMkDir.doRun(SvnRemoteRemoteMkDir.java:65)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteRemoteMkDir.run(SvnRemoteRemoteMkDir.java:39)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteRemoteMkDir.run(SvnRemoteRemoteMkDir.java:35)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1235)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl17.SVNClientImpl.mkdirRemote(SVNClientImpl.java:2292)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 ... 67 more
2017-4-3 17.43.39Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketConnection.run(SVNSocketConnection.java:57)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 ... 4 more
2017-4-3 17.43.39[,982] ERROR - DeploymentSynchronizerComponent Error while initializing a deployment synchronizer for the super tenant Carbon repository
2017-4-3 17.43.39org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.DeploymentSynchronizerException: Error while attempting to create the directory: http://svnrepo/svn/repos/repo/-1234
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.subversion.SVNBasedArtifactRepository.handleException(SVNBasedArtifactRepository.java:831)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.subversion.SVNBasedArtifactRepository.checkRemoteDirectory(SVNBasedArtifactRepository.java:250)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.subversion.SVNBasedArtifactRepository.init(SVNBasedArtifactRepository.java:175)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.repository.CarbonRepositoryUtils.newCarbonRepositorySynchronizer(CarbonRepositoryUtils.java:67)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.internal.DeploymentSynchronizerComponent.initDeploymentSynchronizerForSuperTenant(DeploymentSynchronizerComponent.java:98)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.internal.DeploymentSynchronizerComponent.activate(DeploymentSynchronizerComponent.java:67)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:514)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.start(CarbonServerManager.java:219)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.activate(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:94)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1269)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1182)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1072)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5368)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5660)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-4-3 17.43.39Caused by: org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.SVNClientException: org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: E175002: timed out waiting for server
2017-4-3 17.43.39svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/repos/repo'
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.javahl.AbstractJhlClientAdapter.mkdir(AbstractJhlClientAdapter.java:2733)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.subversion.SVNBasedArtifactRepository.checkRemoteDirectory(SVNBasedArtifactRepository.java:248)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 ... 64 more
2017-4-3 17.43.39Caused by: org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: E175002: timed out waiting for server
2017-4-3 17.43.39svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/repos/repo'
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException.fromException(ClientException.java:68)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl17.SVNClientImpl.getClientException(SVNClientImpl.java:1492)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl17.SVNClientImpl.mkdirRemote(SVNClientImpl.java:2294)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl17.SVNClientImpl.mkdir(SVNClientImpl.java:597)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.javahl.AbstractJhlClientAdapter.mkdir(AbstractJhlClientAdapter.java:2730)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 ... 65 more
2017-4-3 17.43.39Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: timed out waiting for server
2017-4-3 17.43.39svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/repos/repo'
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:106)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:90)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:775)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:375)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:363)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:710)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:627)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:102)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1032)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.checkPath(DAVRepository.java:214)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteRemoteMkDir.addURLParents(SvnRemoteRemoteMkDir.java:156)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteRemoteMkDir.doRun(SvnRemoteRemoteMkDir.java:65)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteRemoteMkDir.run(SvnRemoteRemoteMkDir.java:39)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteRemoteMkDir.run(SvnRemoteRemoteMkDir.java:35)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1235)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl17.SVNClientImpl.mkdirRemote(SVNClientImpl.java:2292)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 ... 67 more
2017-4-3 17.43.39Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketConnection.run(SVNSocketConnection.java:57)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
2017-4-3 17.43.39 ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was docker containers could not communicate with each other when they are deployed on different hosts.